# Bootstrap Switch value passes as 'on' via ajax even it is unchecked

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, checkbox

I have a simple form with two Bootstrap switches.

```
<div class="row mt-5">
                    <div class="col-xl-3">
                        <h5>Minutes</h5>
                        <div class="div ml-3">
                            <div class="form-check form-switch" >
                                <input class="form-check-input minutes" type="checkbox" id="minutes" name="minutes">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-xl-3">
                        <h5>Accounts</h5>
                        <div class="div ml-3">
                        <div class="form-check form-switch" >
                                <input class="form-check-input minutes" type="checkbox" id="accounts" name="accounts">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-xl-6 pt-3">
                        <button class="btn btn-success btn-lg float-end" type="submit" onclick="addEntry();" name="record" id="record"> <i class="fas fa-save"></i> Record</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

And this is the script

```
<script>
function addEntry() {
    jQuery.ajax({
    url: "do-add-data.php",
    data:'+'accounts='+$("#accounts").val()+'&minutes='+$("#minutes").val(),
    type: "POST",
    success:function(data){
    $("#addrecord").html(data);
    },
    error:function (){}
    });
    }
</script>
```

When I check `do-add-data.php` values of `accounts` & `minutes` are 'on' always even if the switches are not switched on (not checked)

How can I resolve this issue?

Comment: It seems you forgot the <form> tag

Comment: `data:'+'&accounts='` Looks wrong with the starting quote

Comment: @MicheleDeFalco -  I haven't used form tag since data pass through ajax

Comment: @brombeer - Sorry. I was a typo. I have corrected it

Comment: Build your `data` parameter as an object to avoid the potential for such mistakes: `data: { "accounts": $("#accounts").val(), "minutes": $("#minutes").val() }`. jQuery will url-encode it for you automatically, which is much more reliable.

Comment: _"values of accounts & minutes are 'on' always even if the switches are not switched on (not checked)"_ - that's _because_ you are reading the value. The _value_ of a checkbox input field is either the one you _specified_ via the `value` attribute - or `on` by default, if you don't specify one. That value will only get _added_ to the form submission data set, if the checkbox was checked - you are however adding it in either case.

Comment: If you _had_ used a form - then jQuery's `serialize` method could do the work your for here already; if you don't want to use a form, then you will have to check whether the boxes are checked first yourself, _before_ you add the corresponding parameter for them to your query string.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have misunderstood how checkboxes work.

You didn't specify any `value` for your checkboxes in the HTML, so their default `value` will be "on" (as per https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/checkbox#value).

But the `value` of the checkbox is independent from whether it's checked or not.

If you want to inform the server whether your checkboxes are checked or not, you need to interrogate their `checked` property. Here's an example:

```js
function addEntry() {
  jQuery.ajax({
    url: "do-add-data.php",
    data: {
      "accounts": $("#accounts").prop("checked"),
      "minutes": $("#minutes").prop("checked")
    },
    type: "POST",
    success: function(data) {
      $("#addrecord").html(data);
    },
    error: function() {}
  });
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="row mt-5">
  <div class="col-xl-3">
    <h5>Minutes</h5>
    <div class="div ml-3">
      <div class="form-check form-switch">
        <input class="form-check-input minutes" type="checkbox" id="minutes" name="minutes">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-xl-3">
    <h5>Accounts</h5>
    <div class="div ml-3">
      <div class="form-check form-switch">
        <input class="form-check-input minutes" type="checkbox" id="accounts" name="accounts">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-xl-6 pt-3">
    <button class="btn btn-success btn-lg float-end" type="submit" onclick="addEntry();" name="record" id="record"> <i class="fas fa-save"></i> Record</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

This will send `true` or `false` to the server for each checkbox, depending on whether it's checked or not.

References:

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/checkbox#value
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/checkbox#checked
- https://api.jquery.com/prop/